# A nonzero integral of a closed differential form over the torus implies it is not exact

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\omega$ be a closed differential form over the torus $T$. Suppose
$$\int_T \omega \neq 0.$$
Why does it follow that $\omega$ represents a nonzero cohomology class on $T$? I assume this somehow follows from Stokes' Theorem, and this is what I have thought of so far.

Assume that $\omega$ does not represent a nonzero cohomology class of $T$. Then it must be exact, so write it as $\omega = d\beta$. Then
$$\int_{\partial T} \beta = \int_T d\beta = \int_T\omega \neq 0.$$
But this is a contradiction, as $\partial T = \emptyset$ which implies
$$ \int_{\partial T} \beta = 0.$$Hence $\omega$ must represent a nonzero cohomology class.

Is this correct? If so, I assume this statement does not hold in general for manifolds with nonzero boundary?

Comment: Correct, and the statement does not hold for manifolds with boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition
$$ H^{2}_{\text{de Rham}}(T;\mathbf{R}) \cong \frac{\{ \text{closed $2$-forms} \}}{\{ \text{exact $2$-forms} \}}. $$
If $\omega$ is closed (as all $2$-forms on a $2$-manifold are), then $\omega$ determines a (de Rham) cohomology class. This cohomology class is trivial precisely when $\omega$ is exact. By Stokes's theorem, $\omega = d\eta$ would imply
$$ \int_{T} \omega = \int_{\partial T} \eta = 0. $$
In sum,
$$ \text{$\omega$ determines the trivial cohomology class} \iff \text{$\omega$ is exact} \implies \int_{T} \omega = 0. $$
Hence, the hypothesis that $\omega$ has nonzero integral immediately implies that $\omega$ determines a nontrivial cohomology class.

We used above the fact that $\partial T$ is empty. Indeed, the statement does not generalize to surfaces with boundary. Here is a counterexample.

Consider the cylinder $S^{1} \times [0,1]$ with the $2$-form $\omega = d\theta \wedge dt$. The Künneth formula reveals that all $2$-forms on $S^{1} \times [0,1]$ are exact. Indeed,
$$ d(-td\theta) = -dt \wedge d\theta = d\theta \wedge dt = \omega. $$
We can now use Stokes's theorem to evaluate the integral.
$$ \int_{S^{1} \times [0,1]} d\theta \wedge dt = \int_{\partial(S^{1} \times [0,1])} -td\theta = -2\pi. $$